# Possible Memory leak while updating current location marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks

I am developing an android application that involves google maps and I am updating the current location of the user. Using the memory monitor, I observed that there is a small amount of memory which gets allocated every time onLocationChanged() of LocationListener gets called. This function calls drawMarker() where in I update the marker. I am fairly new to google maps and memory management and I just want to know if there is a memory leak in my code or if that is how things work. A considerable amount of memory gets allocated when I touch the map and I assume it is related to the internal code and not mine because I don't do anything when a map is touched. Below is the code which gets executed every time location gets updated and if I switch off my GPS, then there is not location update and hence no increase in memory.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // redraw the marker when get location update.
    drawMarker(location);
    location = null;
}

private void drawMarker(Location location){

    mMap.clear();

    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    if(currentLocationMarker == null) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(currentPosition)
                .snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng:" + location.getLongitude()));
    }


    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 15);
    mMap.animateCamera(update);
    update = null;
    currentPosition = null;
    location=null;
}
```

The same LatLng object cannot be reused and hence a new object needs to be created every time. I guess the increase in memory is coming from the two memory allocation statements that gets executed every time but I'm not sure if this is a concern. I don't see any garbage collection happening either unless I explicitly ask for one from android studio.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If when you manually trigger GC the memory is then deallocated it means you are not really leaking anything.

A good suggestion I have is to integrate Leak Canary on your project:

https://github.com/square/leakcanary

It is a very good library that allows you to find if there are any memory leaks in your application. 
It takes automatic periodically memory dumps and compares them using a fork of MAT (Memory Analyzer Tool)

Comment: Oh! I see. So if there was a memory leak, wouldn't a explicit GC not deallocate the memory? How would I be able to detect a leak ?